# values for $x$ in which the series converges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

I have seen some videos and looked up different examples on the internet but non seem to help me start an approach to my problem which is the following : find all the values $a$ in which the series converges:
$$ 
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac a{n+2}-\frac1{n+4}\right)
$$ 
most of the examples ive seen have to deal with powers, which i understood after seeing alot of examples, but havent come across an example that helps me with my problem. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried working with it as a telescoping series?

Comment: You might want to use two different letters, one for the term and another on top of the sum. This is really bugging me.

Comment: I made an edit that I believe restates the problem correctly. If it's a finite sum, there's no question of convergence.

Comment: then you must compute the limit for $n$ tends to infinity

Comment: @GTonyJacobs thanks i was trying to edit that part, fairly new to this format of writing equations. sorry for any inconveniences. I would want a different approach then telescoping series, one using  comparison, to compare it to another series.

Comment: Try actually calculating $\frac{a}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+4}$ to a single fraction, then use the comparison test, keeping in mind that $\sum \frac1n$ diverges, while $\sum\frac1{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: Usually, the way I work with telescoping series is by writing an expression for the $k$-th partial sum, and then taking its limit.

Comment: Actually, I like @Arthur's comment. This one might not work as a telescoping series.

Answer (score 1):

Taken separately, the two terms form a diverging harmonic series, and except for a few terms you get $(a-1)H_n$. The only way to counteract that is to make $a=1$ so that cancellation enters into play and only the "few terms" remain.

Now,

$$\frac1{n+2}-\frac1{n+4}=\frac2{(n+2)(n+4)},$$ leading to a converging series.

Answer (score 0):

your finit sum is given by the following formula $$- \left( n+3 \right) ^{-1}- \left( n+4 \right) ^{-1}+ \left( \alpha-1
 \right) \Psi \left( n+3 \right) +{\frac{7}{12}}- \left( \alpha-1
 \right)  \left( 3/2-\gamma \right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$u_n=\frac{a}{n}\frac{1}{1+\frac{4}{n}}-\frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{n}}$$
$$=\frac{a}{n}(1-\frac{4}{n}+....$$

$$-\frac{1}{n}(1-\frac{2}{n}+....$$
it converges if the coefficient of $\frac{1}{n}$ in Asymptotic expansion is zero, which gives

$$a-1=0.$$

Comment: @BarryCipra No i made the correction. now it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic idea:  For any value of $a$, we have

$${a\over n+2}-{1\over n+4}={(a-1)n+(4a-2)\over n^2+6n+8}$$

If $a\not=1$, then

$${(a-1)n+(4a-2)\over n^2+6n+8}\approx{a-1\over n}$$

for large $n$, which means the infinite sum is comparable to the (divergent) harmonic series when $a\not=1$.  Can you see what happens in the other case, when $a=1$?

There are various ways to make the comparison rigorous.  If you need additional help, please ping with a comment.

Comment: @SimpleArt, thanks! Do we agree now? (Ah, I see we do!)

Comment: :) yup!$\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that

$$\frac a{n+2}-\frac1{n+4}=\frac{(a-1)n+4a-2}{(n+2)(n+4)}$$

Now try limit comparison to $\frac1n$.